# Android - Simple View Refresh

Tags: android, refresh, screen, invalidation, onresume

I don't think my future lies in Android development, as I am consistently failing at the simplest things...

I've got a button with the label "Game Slot 1".  When the user clicks it, I succesfully take them through a couple of activities in which they create a new character.  I save the game name in an SQLite database, and the next time I launch my app, I can quite happily dynamically change "Game Slot 1" to the name of that slot's game from the database.  Perfect.

But how on earth do I get it to update the view in the same manner when I return to that activity via the back button, or having called finish() on all the subsequent activities?

I'm sure it's something to do with onResume(), and maybe invalidate(), but I just can't seem to find an example.

Is invalidate overkill just to refresh a few UI elements onResume()?

How the heck do you use it, anyway, even if it is?

Is there a better way?

Many thanks in advance for any help offered...just try not to laugh at how simple this probably is! :)

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like something you could do in onResume, just query the database and call setText on the element of interest.  You should not need to explicitly call invalidate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way.  It prompted me to realise I was being very dim indeed.